# Why isn't my select by attributes query working?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, sql, error, query

I'm running ArcMap 10.1.

I have a point feature class joined to a table and am trying to query a field.

If I do [field] = 'TEST', it selects all the fields.

But if I do [field] LIKE 'TES%', it doesn't work.

Any idea why the LIKE command isn't working?

Comment: Double quotes are for field names and single quotes are for field values, as far as I know. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Sorry, it is only single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wildcard to use with LIKE depends on the data source.

You are using square brackets as field name delimiters. So I suppose you are using a *Personal Geodatabase*.

The wildcards you have to use to query a *personal geodatabases* are asterisk (*) for any number of characters and question mark (?) for one character.

If you use SDE or file based geodatabase you have to use percent symbol (%) and underscore (_).

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks. For some reason I never knew you had to use an asterisk for personal geodatabases.

Comment: With a personal geodatabase you have to use the same syntax as Microsoft Access (* and ?).

Comment: here's a little tip - on the Select By Attributes dialog, at the lower left, there is a button which changes to show the relevant wildcard character for each dataset. It shows * or % depending on the chosen layer type.